# RestyGWT & GWT integration: Cannot GET Resource

Tags: java, rest, gwt, resty-gwt

**OBJECTIVE:**

I'm using GWT and trying to call an existing Twitter REST Service using RestyGWT client

**PROBLEM:**

I am not receiving a response to my GET request to "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/mentions_timeline.json"

**THINGS I'VE TRIED:**

I've looked at RestyGWT's documentation, and I couldn't come across a concrete example on how to call third party REST services.
Tried calling a REST service using plaintext return types, same problem.
There must be something I'm doing wrong on a fundamental leve.

**CODE:**

Here's my onModuleLoad:

```
public void onModuleLoad() {

    Resource r = new Resource("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/mentions_timeline.json");

            r.get().send(new JsonCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Method method, JSONValue response) {
                    System.out.println("Twitter response:\tYES");
                    }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Method method, Throwable exception) {
                    System.out.println("Twitter response:\tNO");
                    System.out.println("Exception:\t\t"+exception.toString());
                    System.out.println("Exception Message:\t"+exception.getMessage());
                    System.out.println("Status code:\t\t"+method.getResponse().getStatusCode() );
                    }
            });
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
GWT MODULE LOADED
Twitter response:   NO
Exception:          org.fusesource.restygwt.client.FailedStatusCodeException: 
Exception Message:  
Status code:        0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing a remote service that isn't yours, you typically have to send JSONP requests to work around the same origin policy. So try `r.jsonp()` instead of `r.get()`.

Comment: I can't find any documentation on using jsonp with Resty-GWT.
Here's the output I get when using r.jsonp()
`---------------------------------
GWT MODULE LOADED
Twitter response: NO
Exception:  com.google.gwt.jsonp.client.TimeoutException: Timeout while calling https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/mentions_timeline.json
Exception Message: Timeout while calling https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/mentions_timeline.json
`

Answer (score 0):

jsonp calls the service method atleast, but exception with status code 0. However get doesn't even reach the service method.